# Arduino and Pyserial. Seperate output to different variables

Tags: python-3.x, arduino-uno, pyserial

My arduino board gives me temperature values and light intensity values. 
I want to put the temperature value in a variable, and the light value in another.

Here is piece of my python code:

```
serialArduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
valueRead = serialArduino.readline()
valueRead2 = serialArduino.readline()
```

Program on arduino board:

```
Serial.print(val1);
Serial.print("\n");
Serial.print(val2);
Serial.print("\n");
```

I add these values in 2 different graphs. But they are going up and down. I can see why. I also tried to seperate the values on the arduino board with a comma.

so:

```
Serial.print(val1);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print(val2);
Serial.print("\n");
```

I looked up how to use the split function. But i cant get it to do the job.
But im not sure how to use it so it will store the value before the comma in variable1, and the second in variable2.

Can someone give me a hint or explaination how i should take care of this?
i hope i provided enough information and that my question is clear, if not tell me the information you need.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

On the Python side, assuming the values are floats, and that you are using the comma approach:

```
>>> a = "0.1,0.2"
>>> val1, val2 = [float(x) for x in a.split(",")]
>>> val1, val2
(0.1, 0.2)
```